# How to avoid LazyInitializationException in this method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

> Hello everyone, everything good? And I'm wanting to fetch all users
> passing a filter using the findAll method and the class Example, but I
> always get a lazyLoadException.
>
> I've tried several approaches I can't get something to work to make
> paging with filters work without having this problem.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service("PersonService")
public class PersonService {

    private PersonRepository personRepository;
    
    private final PersonMapper personMapper ;
    
    public Page<PersonDTO> findByExample(PersonDTO personExample, PageRequest pageOptions) {
        return personRepository.findAll(Example.of(personMapper.toModel(personExample)), pageOptions).map(personMapper::toDTO);
    }
}



public class Person implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7358912459265900699L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name ="first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name ="last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name ="cpf",nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String cpf;
    
    @Column(name ="data_nascimento")
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDate createdAt;
}
```

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: one.digitalinovation.bootcampgft.personapi.model.Person.phones, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:606) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at one.digitalinovation.bootcampgft.personapi.mapper.PersonMapperImpl.phoneListToPhoneDTOList(PersonMapperImpl.java:108) ~[classes/:na]
at one.digitalinovation.bootcampgft.personapi.mapper.PersonMapperImpl.toDTO(PersonMapperImpl.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:999) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.domain.Chunk.getConvertedContent(Chunk.java:173) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
at org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl.map(PageImpl.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
at one.digitalinovation.bootcampgft.personapi.service.PersonService.findByExample(PersonService.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
at one.digitalinovation.bootcampgft.personapi.controller.PersonController.findPerson(PersonController.java:127) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]

Comment: Please edit your question to fix your logcat, just take necessary logtcat only.

Answer (score 0):

There is no enough information on your questions, please add more details.
Based on the information given, I'd suggest to you check if you are inside a transaction bounded method, in the other case it's expected to have this error.

Take a look in this link: https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make your service method transactional. Basically when defining the fetch type to Lazy relative to a mapped entity within another entity, Hibernate does not initialise the entire mapped entity but keeps this 'persistent bag'.

To access this persistent bag you'll have to be within a Transactional method. As soon as the transaction ends the persistent bag is no more accessible

Anyways to do so just annotate the method with @Transaction as so

```
    @Transactional
    public Page<PersonDTO> findByExample(PersonDTO personExample, PageRequest pageOptions) {
            return personRepository.findAll(Example.of(personMapper.toModel(personExample)), pageOptions).map(personMapper::toDTO);
    }
```